# React saving dynamic UI components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-redux

Is there any way in react to save UI and load it later ?

I came across several solutions like saving the UI state into a database but this solution is not smart if you are building a dynamic dashboard or a page builder for example with unlimited number of possibilities.

Also we can use [reactdomserver](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) from server or client side , data should be passed as props but in the case of a dynamic dashboard this solution will be very hard to implement.

I am new to react and will be very happy to know that there is a solution that can save dynamic content to a file or a database.

Answer (score 1):

Don't save the DOM when you're doing React. You will always find a case that will break whatever assumptions you initially made.

Save the state/props that lead to the UI you need. Then pass those same props again to your component.

Comment: lets take the dynamic dashboard example, how you will save the state ?
there is dynamic content like charts.

Comment: I have worked on something exactly like this at a previous job, and saving the props as a JSON object worked perfectly for us. Imagine you have a chart, this chart takes props (for example the axes, zoom, colors) you can send those to a server to be saved. when the user reloads the page, you fetch that data from the server and pass it as props, your chart will look exactly the same as before.

Comment: this also worked perfectly for tables with the order of the columns, filters, sorting etc..